# An entry with parentheses in Python 3.5 only continues if the Enter key is pressed twice

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a simple exercise to identify if the parentheses used in an equation are correct, but when I try input an equation like this a+(b*c)-2-a , 
I have to press enter twice. This only happens inside the EOF block.
What could be wrong? Thank you very much!

```
while True:
    try:
        x = input()
        z = []
        for y in x:
            if y == '(':
                z.append(y)
            elif y == ')':
                z.append(y)
        q = ''.join(z)
        d = 0
        while d == 0:
            if q.count('()') != 0:
                q = q.replace('()', '')
            else:
                if q.count('(') >= 1 or q.count(')') >= 1:
                    print('incorrect')
                else:
                    print('correct')
            d = 1
    except:
        break
```

Comment: What did you try thus far?

Comment: @confusedandamused you can also replicate in Python 2 if you swap `input` for `raw_input`; it's an MCVE. I'm actually stumped myself, the first input passes `if q.count('()') != 0:` and will print a message after `q = q.replace('()', '')` but then it (seemingly) goes back to `input`.

Comment: Ah, solved it. Missed one of the loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `while True` loops. On the first time around, you enter `while d == 0:` with a valid balance of parentheses meaning that `if q.count('()') != 0:` is `True`. That `while` loop then breaks, because `d` is incremented by 1. But the `print` statements require `if q.count('()') != 0:` to be `False`. Therefore, you start the whole loop again due to the very first `while True:`, press enter (which is effectively an invalid input for your algorithm) which allows you to get to:

```
else:
    if q.count('(') >= 1 or q.count(')') >= 1:
        print('incorrect')
    else:
        print('correct')
```

Comment: thanks roganjosh!! I forgot one identation for d = 1, now the code works fine

Comment: @plex you're welcome, that was actually quite deceiving at first glance :)

Comment: I'm a beginner in this python world, thanks for the quick response